# Select a string from a specific place - T-SQl

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Let's say I have following records in my table.

```
4 - Mar 1 thru Apr 11
13 - Dec 01 thru Dec 31
```

I want to select the string so that the output would be,

```
Mar 1 thru Apr 11
Dec 01 thru Dec 31
```

How can I do that?

Thank you

Comment: Is the data actually structured like that instead of two `DATETIME` fields?

Comment: Just use `charindex` to find the index of the hyphen, then use `substring` to extract the remaining portion

Comment: Yes, there is a column which contains values in above listed format. I wish to remove everything before the start month name and get the output.

Comment: I was looking into charindex/substring but can't really figure out the sln. (don't have a solid concept of charindex/substring)

Comment: I hope you need this for a one_time fix of poor way the data is stored, not for production code that will run repeatedly.

Comment: umm, this query will be used for reporting but might run once in awhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could use:

`CHARINDEX ( expressionToFind ,expressionToSearch [ , start_location ] )`

See for documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx

So, this will be:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING([*FieldName*], CHARINDEX('-', [*FieldName*])+2, 252) FROM [*Table*]
```

`252` is the number of characters, and that's the default length of `nvarchar` fields. Increase it or decrease this number if need be.

I put `+2` to strip out the `-` (dash and white space).

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of choices, I will use **SELECT** with **SUBSTR** and **LEN** clause, (see this page: http://oreilly.com/catalog/sqlnut/chapter/ch04.html)

Data:
4 - Mar 1 thru Apr 11
13 - Dec 01 thru Dec 31

SELECT SUBSTR(your-field,4,TRIM(LEN(your-field)-4)) FROM your-table;

**OUTPUT:**
Mar 1 thru Apr 11
Dec 01 thru Dec 31

**NOTES** 
- SUBSTR: return part of argument
- LEN: return lenght of argument
- TRIM: return lenght without spaces

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT REPLACE((SUBSTRING('4 - Mar 1 thru Apr 11', CHARINDEX(' - ', '4 - Mar 1 thru Apr 11'), LEN('4 - Mar 1 thru Apr 11'))),' - ','')
```

This also works,

I will check out your option now.

Thank you for all your help guys.